# jQuery messes up the z-indexes of DIVs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, z-index

I'm finishing up this website, there is just one little problem. Whenever I click next (volgende), the DIV with z-index 1 (the other 2 have 2 and 3) shows up in front of the other 2 and stays there. http://luukvanaggelen.com/test/test2.html This is the website, I'm using the jQuery rotate plugin. This is the code I use to move to the next page.

```
$(volgende).click(function(){
    if ( container <= max_container ) 
        $(('#container'+container)).rotate({animateTo:150});
    container++;
})
```

I honestly have no clue how this is possible let alone how to fix it...

Comment: Have you looked at the CSS accompanying the rotate plugin? Does that contain any reference to z-index?

Comment: Have you tried resetting the z-index you want on the item after animation is finished then? Store it in a variable before you start your animation then re-assign it once the animation is complete.

Comment: Hi Mentatmatt. The plugin does not have a CSS accompied. Thanks for the reply. Speedy, I have done this before, but the z-index remains the same all the time. So even if I saved and applied it back, nothing would change.. Maybe it has something to do with the jQuery rotate plugin?? I'm using this one; http://jqueryrotate.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jQueryRotate.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for my messed up code, change the code to this and tell me if it works:

```
max_container=3;
min_container=1;
container=0;
$(volgende).click(function(){if ( container <= max_container ) {container++;$(('#container'+container)).rotate({animateTo:150});}})
$(volgende).click(function(){if ( container >= min_container ){ $(('#container'+container)).rotate({animateTo:0});container--;}})
```

EDIT: Sorry didn't saw your question clearly, you should put z-index in the div container, not on home inside the div, and it is always better to using order instead of z-index, you must place container 3 after 2 and place 2 after 1 so the third one will be in behind of the second one

Comment: Hi Sijav, thanks for the reply! It's not working, probably because the second line moves the same container right back to 0, am I right? The DIVs do keep the right order!

Comment: @luuk-van-aggelen you didn't change the code to mine though please change your code to this new one to see if the problems persist or not

Comment: I am using your code, I program locally. It is working after I put var before the variables and changed the second volgende into vorige ;) haha.  That didn't fix the z-index problem tho. However after your edit, I put the Z-index on the div container and it worked perfectly. Therefor you are my hero once again! Thanks so much man!

Comment: @LuukvanAggelen Glad it helped, please feel free to drop any further question.